# What is the correct way to destroy the CMFCMenuBar and CMFCToolBar and recreate them?

Tags: mfc, dpi

I wanted to change a MFC app to be per-monitor aware. Most things work fine but the menu and tool bars don't.  I'd like to simple recreate them presumably picking up the current DPI. I basically tried:

```
  if (m_wndToolBar.GetSafeHwnd()) {
    m_wndToolBar.DestroyWindow();
  }

  if (m_wndMenuBar.GetSafeHwnd()) {
    m_wndMenuBar.DestroyWindow();
  }
```

followed by the normal create process but on `m_wndMenuBar.Create()` it asserts.

This is where it fails inside the `m_wndMenuBar.Create(this)`

```
if (!CMFCBaseToolBar::Create(
        GetGlobalData()->RegisterWindowClass(_T("Afx:ToolBar")), dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID, 0))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main window is derived from `CFrameWnd`, you can reload the menu-bar from the application's resources, which *should* reset it (where `resource` is the ID for the main menu and accelerator table):

```
    CMyFrameWnd *pFrame = dynamic_cast<CMyFrameWnd*>(AfxGetApp()->AfxGetMainWnd());
    if (pFrame && pFrame->IsWindowEnabled())) {
        HMENU defMenu = LoadMenu(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(resource));
        pFrame->m_wndMenuBar.CreateFromMenu(defMenu, TRUE, TRUE);
        pFrame->LoadAccelTable(MAKEINTRESOURCE(resource));
    }
```

You can *probably* do a similar operation on the toolbar(s), using the [`CMFCToolBar::LoadToolBar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctoolbar-class?view=vs-2019#loadtoolbar), member, but I haven't used or tested that function.

Comment: It didn't change the font size.  I was hoping it would scale like it does on startup.  So the idea was to just destroy existing items, let it create them again, and MFC would automatically set the size (in per-monitor dpi mode).

Answer (score 0):

To handle DPI Scaling in per-monitor mode.  This seems to work for the default menubar and toolbar.

```
  class CCustomMFCToolBar : public CMFCToolBar
  {
    public:
    BOOL FullRestoreOriginalState()
    {
      // ensure restore original
        if (m_uiOriginalResID == 0)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

      // remove existing images
      ResetAllImages();

      // reset id so bitmaps are loaded again
      UINT resid=m_uiOriginalResID;
      m_uiOriginalResID=0;

      // handle loading toolbar and bitmaps
        BOOL bRes = LoadToolBar(resid);

        AdjustLayout();

        if (IsFloating())
        {
            RecalcLayout();
        }
        else if (m_pParentDockBar != NULL)
        {
            CSize sizeCurr = CalcFixedLayout(FALSE, IsHorizontal());
            CRect rect;
            GetWindowRect(rect);

            if (rect.Size() != sizeCurr)
            {
                SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, sizeCurr.cx, sizeCurr.cy, SWP_NOMOVE  | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
                UpdateVirtualRect();
            }
            m_pDockBarRow->ArrangePanes(this);
            AFXGetParentFrame(this)->RecalcLayout();
        }

        RedrawWindow(NULL, NULL, RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW | RDW_ERASE);

        return bRes;
    }

  };
```

Catch the DPI Change here or all items set back to restart since WM_SETTINGCHANGED is called after WM_DPICHANGED

```
void CMainFrame::OnSettingChange(UINT uFlags, LPCTSTR lpszSection)
{
  CFrameWndEx::OnSettingChange(uFlags, lpszSection);
  g_DPIHelper.SetChangedScaleForWindow(m_hWnd);

 
  struct GlobalDataUnprotect : AFX_GLOBAL_DATA
  {
    #define AFX_FONT_NAME_OFFICE       _T("Tahoma")
    #define AFX_FONT_NAME_OFFICE_2007  _T("Segoe UI")
    #define AFX_FONT_NAME_DEFAULT      _T("MS Sans Serif")
    #define AFX_FONT_NAME_VERT         _T("Arial")
    #define AFX_FONT_NAME_MARLETT      _T("Marlett")

     // This is a copy of UpdateFonts() modified a couple places to
     // set the correct / changed scaling.

    static int CALLBACK FontFamilyProcFonts(const LOGFONT FAR* lplf, const TEXTMETRIC FAR* lptm, ULONG ulFontType, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        ENSURE(lplf != NULL);
        ENSURE(lParam != NULL);

        CString strFont = lplf->lfFaceName;
        return strFont.CollateNoCase((LPCTSTR) lParam) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    void UpdateScaledFonts()
    {
        CWindowDC dc(NULL);

        m_dblRibbonImageScale = static_cast<double>(g_DPIHelper.GetScale())/100.0;

        if (m_dblRibbonImageScale > 1. && m_dblRibbonImageScale < 1.1)
        {
            m_dblRibbonImageScale = 1.;
        }

        if (fontRegular.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontRegular.Detach());
        }

        if (fontTooltip.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontTooltip.Detach());
        }

        if (fontBold.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontBold.Detach());
        }

        if (fontDefaultGUIBold.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontDefaultGUIBold.Detach());
        }

        if (fontUnderline.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontUnderline.Detach());
        }

        if (fontDefaultGUIUnderline.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontDefaultGUIUnderline.Detach());
        }

        if (fontVert.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontVert.Detach());
        }

        if (fontVertCaption.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontVertCaption.Detach());
        }

        if (fontMarlett.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontMarlett.Detach());
        }

        if (fontSmall.GetSafeHandle() != NULL)
        {
            ::DeleteObject(fontSmall.Detach());
        }

        // Initialize fonts:

        NONCLIENTMETRICS info;
        info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
        GetNonClientMetrics (info);

        LOGFONT lf;
        memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));

        lf.lfCharSet = (BYTE) GetTextCharsetInfo(dc.GetSafeHdc(), NULL, 0);

        lf.lfHeight = info.lfMenuFont.lfHeight;
        lf.lfWeight = info.lfMenuFont.lfWeight;
        lf.lfItalic = info.lfMenuFont.lfItalic;

        //------------------
        // Adjust font size:
        //------------------
        int nFontHeight = lf.lfHeight < 0 ? -lf.lfHeight : lf.lfHeight;
        if (nFontHeight <= 12)
        {
            nFontHeight = 11;
        }
        else if (!m_bDontReduceFontHeight)
        {
            nFontHeight--;
        }

        lf.lfHeight = (lf.lfHeight < 0) ? -nFontHeight : nFontHeight;

      lf.lfHeight=g_DPIHelper.ScaleNonClientMetricsFont(lf.lfHeight);

        // Check if we should use system font
        lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, info.lfMenuFont.lfFaceName);

        BOOL fUseSystemFont = m_bUseSystemFont || (info.lfMenuFont.lfCharSet > SYMBOL_CHARSET);
        if (!fUseSystemFont)
        {
            // Check for "Segoe UI" or "Tahoma" font existance:
            if (::EnumFontFamilies(dc.GetSafeHdc(), NULL, FontFamilyProcFonts, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR) AFX_FONT_NAME_OFFICE_2007) == 0)
            {
                // Found! Use MS Office 2007 font!
                lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, AFX_FONT_NAME_OFFICE_2007);
          lf.lfQuality=5; // CLEARTYPE_QUALITY;
            }
            else if (::EnumFontFamilies(dc.GetSafeHdc(), NULL, FontFamilyProcFonts, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR) AFX_FONT_NAME_OFFICE) == 0)
            {
                // Found! Use MS Office font!
                lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, AFX_FONT_NAME_OFFICE);
            }
            else
            {
                // Not found. Use default font:
                lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, AFX_FONT_NAME_DEFAULT);
            }
        }
    
        fontRegular.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

        // Create small font:
        LONG lfHeightSaved = lf.lfHeight;

        lf.lfHeight = (long)((1. + abs(lf.lfHeight)) * 2 / 3);
        if (lfHeightSaved < 0)
        {
            lf.lfHeight = -lf.lfHeight;
        }

        fontSmall.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
        lf.lfHeight = lfHeightSaved;

        // Create tooltip font:
        NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
        ncm.cbSize = sizeof(ncm);
        GetNonClientMetrics (ncm);

        lf.lfItalic = ncm.lfStatusFont.lfItalic;
        lf.lfWeight = ncm.lfStatusFont.lfWeight;
        fontTooltip.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

        lf.lfItalic = info.lfMenuFont.lfItalic;
        lf.lfWeight = info.lfMenuFont.lfWeight;

        // Create "underline" font:
        lf.lfUnderline = TRUE;
        fontUnderline.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
        lf.lfUnderline = FALSE;

        // Create bold font:
        lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
        fontBold.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

        // Create Marlett font:
        BYTE bCharSet = lf.lfCharSet;
        lf.lfWeight = info.lfMenuFont.lfWeight;
        lf.lfCharSet = SYMBOL_CHARSET;
        lf.lfWeight = 0;
      lf.lfHeight=g_DPIHelper.ScaleNonClientMetricsFont(::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENUCHECK) - 1);
        lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, AFX_FONT_NAME_MARLETT);

        fontMarlett.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
        lf.lfCharSet = bCharSet; // Restore charset

        // Create vertical font:
        CFont font;
        if (font.CreateStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT))
        {
            if (font.GetLogFont(&lf) != 0)
            {
                lf.lfOrientation = 900;
                lf.lfEscapement = 2700;

          lf.lfHeight = g_DPIHelper.ScaleNonClientMetricsFont(info.lfMenuFont.lfHeight);
                lf.lfWeight = info.lfMenuFont.lfWeight;
                lf.lfItalic = info.lfMenuFont.lfItalic;

                {
                    lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, AFX_FONT_NAME_VERT);
                }

                fontVert.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

                lf.lfEscapement = 900;
                fontVertCaption.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
            }
        }

        // Create dialog underline and bold fonts:
        CFont* pDefaultGUIFont = CFont::FromHandle((HFONT) GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT));
        ASSERT_VALID(pDefaultGUIFont);
        pDefaultGUIFont->GetLogFont(&lf);

        lf.lfUnderline = TRUE;
        fontDefaultGUIUnderline.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
        lf.lfUnderline = FALSE;

        lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
        fontDefaultGUIBold.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

        UpdateTextMetrics();

      extern CObList afxAllToolBars;

        // Notify toolbars about font changing:
        for (POSITION posTlb = afxAllToolBars.GetHeadPosition(); posTlb != NULL;)
        {
            CMFCToolBar* pToolBar = (CMFCToolBar*) afxAllToolBars.GetNext(posTlb);
            ENSURE(pToolBar != NULL);

            if (CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(pToolBar->m_hWnd) != NULL)
            {
                ASSERT_VALID(pToolBar);
                pToolBar->OnGlobalFontsChanged();
            }
        }
    }

  };

  GlobalDataUnprotect *globaldata=reinterpret_cast<GlobalDataUnprotect*>(GetGlobalData());
  globaldata->UpdateScaledFonts();


  m_wndToolBar.CleanUpLockedImages();
  m_wndToolBar.FullRestoreOriginalState();
 
}
```